# Reading dat file into matrix in matlab with different different amounts of data each row

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I'm trying to write a matlab function that will load a data into a matrix. The problem is the data has one more value each row. So I can't use load unfortunately, so I'm trying to use fgetl.

The data looks like:

```
143234 
454323 354654
543223 343223 325465
```

etc

What I did is create a matrix of zeros, the dimensions being the height and the longest string of data. To put the data into the matrix I used fgetl to read each row and then used textscan to split the data up at whitespace. Then I used str2num (I think this is where the error is) to convert the string to a number.

First heres my code:

```
%READTRI Opens the triangle dat file and turns it into a matrix

fid = fopen('triangledata.dat');

%create matrix of zeros for the data to be retrieved
trimat = zeros(15,15);

%Check to see if the file loaded properly
if fid == -1
disp('File load error')
else
%if it does, continue

%read each line of data into a
while feof(fid) == 0

    %run through line by line
    aline = fgetl(fid);

    %split aline into parts by whitespace
    splitstr = textscan(aline,'%s','delimiter',' ');

    %This determines what row of the matrix the for loop writes to
    rowCount = 1;

    %run through cell array to get the numbers out and write them to
    %the matrix
    for i = 1:length(splitstr)

        %convert to number
        num = str2num(splitstr{i});

        %write num to matrix
        trimat(rowCount, i) = num;

    end

    %iterate rowCount
    rowCount = rowCount + 1;
end
%close the file
closeresult = fclose(fid);

%check for errors
if closeresult == 0
    disp('File close successful')
else
    disp('File close not successful')
end
end



end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error using str2num (line 33)
Requires string or character array input.

Error in readTri (line 32)
        num = str2num(splitstr{i});
```

What bothers me is that when I try, in the interactive console the same thing that goes on in the loop i.e. import aline, split it into a cell array using textscan, then use num2str to convert it to a integer. Everything works. So either the way I'm using num2str is wrong or the for loop is doing something funky.

I was just hoping for ideas, there is a LOT of data so adding zeros to make load work is not possible.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dlmread instead of load or fgetl
It automatically returns a matrix with zeros whenever the line is not as long as the longest.
Just do

```
matrix = dlmread('triangledata.dat');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `textscan`?

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f');
fclose(fid);

res = cell2mat(C)
```

The result is

```
res =

  143234         NaN         NaN
  454323      354654         NaN
  543223      343223      325465
```

where missing values are `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to learn some more about MATLAB file I/O before I start projects like this :/